# Laravel 5.7: Laravel Collective Form to html form

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

I have the following laravel collective form code

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['CategoryController@sub8', $item1->id], 'method' => 'post']) !!}
{{Form::label('postaladdress', 'Postal Address')}}
{{Form::text('postaladdress',null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
{{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') }}

{{ Form::submit('Change Postal Address') }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

How can i get this in normal html form?

Comment: View the source code of the generated page (or inspect the element) to get the "normal html form"

Comment: thanks but unfortunately im unable to load a page with laravel collective

Comment: Why so? Do you get any errors when using Collective Forms?

Comment: Each of those methods renders an element, like `<form>`, `<label>`, `<input type='text'/>`, `<input type='hidden'/>`, `<input type='submit'> `(or `<button>`), and `</form>`. You should be able to look at these and reverse-engineer them to base HTML elements. Have you tried anything? Please remember that Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, and you're expected to make an effort to solve your own problem before posting.

Comment: Press **CTRL + U** and use the code

Comment: very well noted @TimLewis

Comment: @kerbh0lz i failed to use composer to add the collective package

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to figure this out based on what the HTML tags would be but to save yourself time here you go, this is **roughly** what that is:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('CategoryController@sub8', [$item1->id]) }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <label for="postaladdress">Postal Address</label>
    <textarea name="postaladdress" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Change your address">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

I forget if Laravel Collective - HTML will add the CSRF token for you or not, but i added it anyway in the example above.